# Random sample of values with the specified resulting probabilities

Tags: algorithm, probability, random

Imagine we have four symbols - *'a'*, *'b'*, *'c'*, *'d'*. We also have four given probabilities of those symbols appearing in the function output - **P1**, **P2**, **P3**, **P4** (the sum of which is equal to **1**). How would one implement a function which would generate a random sample of three of those symbols, such is that the resulting symbols are present in it with those specified probabilities?

Example: *'a'*, *'b'*, *'c'* and *'d'* have the probabilities of **9/30**, **8/30**, **7/30** and **6/30** respectively. The function outputs various random samples of any three out of those four symbols: *'abc'*, *'dca'*, *'bad'* and so on. We run this function many times, counting the amount of times each of the symbols is encountered in its output. At the end, the value of counts stored for *'a'* divided by the total amount of symbols output should converge to **9/30**, for *'b'* to **8/30**, for *'c'* to **7/30**, and for *'d'* to **6/30**.

E.g. the function generates 10 outputs:

```
adc
dab
bca
dab
dba
cab
dcb
acd
cab
abc
```

which out of 30 symbols contains 9 of *'a'*, 8 of *'b'*, 7 of *'c'* and 6 of *'d'*. This is an idealistic example, of course, as the values would only converge when the number of samples is much larger - but it should hopefully convey the idea.

Obviously, this all is only possible when neither probability is larger than 1/3, since each single sample output would always contain three distinct symbols. It is ok for the function to enter an infinite loop or otherwise behave erratically if it's impossible to satisfy the values provided.

Note: the function should obviously use an RNG, but should otherwise be stateless. Each new invocation should be independent from any of the previous ones, except for the RNG state.

**EDIT**: Even though the description mentions choosing 3 out of 4 values, ideally the algorithm should be able to cope with any sample size.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning behind this statement: _this all is only possible when neither probability is larger than 1/3, since each single sample output would always contain three distinct symbols._ A probability less than 1/3 does not guarantee the symbol won't appear two or even three times in any particular output triple. Is _no duplicates within a triple_ a strict requirement?

Comment: @jogojapan: a probability equal to or larger than 1/3 would result in a symbol which would always have to appear in a triplet. No duplicates is a requirement, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is underdetermined.

If we assign a probability to each string of three letters that we allow, p(abc), p(abd), p(acd) etc xtc we can gernerate a series of equations

```
eqn1: p(abc) + p(abd) + ... others with a "a" ... = p1
  ...
  ...
eqn2: p(abd) + p(acd) + ... others with a "d" ... = p4
```

This has more unknowns than equations, so many ways of solving it. Once a solution is found, by whatever method you choose (use the simplex algorithm if you are me), sample from the probabilities of each string using the roulette method that @alestanis describes.

```
from numpy import *

# using cvxopt-1.1.5
from cvxopt import matrix, solvers 

###########################
# Functions to do some parts

# function to find all valid outputs
def perms(alphabet, length):
    if length == 0:
        yield ""
        return
    for i in range(len(alphabet)):
        val1 = alphabet[i]
        for val2 in perms(alphabet[:i]+alphabet[i+1:], length-1):
            yield val1 + val2


# roulette sampler
def roulette_sampler(values, probs):
    # Create cumulative prob distro
    probs_cum = [sum(probs[:i+1]) for i in range(n_strings)]
    def fun():
        r = random.rand()
        for p,s in zip(probs_cum, values):
            if r < p:
                return s
        # in case of rounding error
        return values[-1]
    return fun


############################
#    Main Part



# create list of all valid strings

alphabet = "abcd"
string_length = 3
alpha_probs = [string_length*x/30. for x in range(9,5,-1)]

# show probs
for a,p in zip(alphabet, alpha_probs):
    print "p("+a+") =",p




# all valid outputs for this particular case
strings = [perm for perm in perms(alphabet, string_length)]
n_strings = len(strings)

# constraints from probabilities p(abc) + p(abd) ... = p(a)
contains = array([[1. if s.find(a) >= 0 else 0. for a in alphabet] for s in strings])
#both = concatenate((contains,wons), axis=1).T # hacky, but whatever
#A = matrix(both)
#b = matrix(alpha_probs + [1.])
A = matrix(contains.T)
b = matrix(alpha_probs)

#also need to constrain to [0,1]
wons = array([[1. for s in strings]])
G = matrix(concatenate((eye(n_strings),wons,-eye(n_strings),-wons)))
h = matrix(concatenate((ones(n_strings+1),zeros(n_strings+1))))

## target matricies for approx KL divergence
# uniform prob over valid outputs
u = 1./len(strings)
P = matrix(eye(n_strings))
q = -0.5*u*matrix(ones(n_strings))
# will minimise p^2 - pq for each p val equally


# Do convex optimisation
sol = solvers.qp(P,q,G,h,A,b)
probs = array(sol['x'])

# Print ouput
for s,p in zip(strings,probs):
    print "p("+s+") =",p
checkprobs = [0. for char in alphabet]
for a,i in zip(alphabet, range(len(alphabet))):
    for s,p in zip(strings,probs):
        if s.find(a) > -1:
            checkprobs[i] += p
    print "p("+a+") =",checkprobs[i]
print "total =",sum(probs)

# Create the sampling function
rndstring = roulette_sampler(strings, probs)


###################
# Verify

print "sampling..."
test_n = 1000
output = [rndstring() for i in xrange(test_n)]

# find which one it is
sampled_freqs = []
for char in alphabet:
    n = 0
    for val in output:
        if val.find(char) > -1:
            n += 1
    sampled_freqs += [n]

print "plotting histogram..."
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(range(0,len(alphabet)),array(sampled_freqs)/float(test_n), width=0.5)
plt.show()
```

EDIT: Python code

Comment: It is under-determined indeed. Certainly there can be multiple solutions. Ideally the output should be as uniformly random as possible, without any correlations between individual symbols within a triplet. And yes, not all possible input probability distributions are possible, I did mention it in the OP. We assume that the one we are given does have a solution, though.

Comment: Did you actually try this code? I don't see how you derive p(a) from the list of p(abc), p(abd) ...; nor how the last loop which uses p(a), ...,p(d) avoids duplicates. Note that eliminating duplicates by simple rejectinon as alestanis suggests won't work because the incidence of symbols in a particular sequence are not independent. (In the 3/4 case, for example, at least one of `a` and `b` must be present, so p(a|b) and p(a|~b) must be different; p(a|~b) is 1

Comment: Well, its pseudocode, so no. But last loop is over `p(abc), p(abd)... etc` It is not rejection sampling. You explicitly calculate the probabilities of each string, then sample from that distribution. It is not particularly efficient though, but quite general and allows you to choose your particular solution by specifying an objective function (must be quadratric in the example above).

Comment: I have done basically the same problem before, but for some unknown reason I wrote it in lisp, and also lost the files. I will make a version in python using cvxopt package.

Comment: yeah, that's a lot better. I was confused by this: `s = ""; for i from 0 to 3: append_to(s, chooseRandomAlestanis(probs_cum)); yield s` which definitely looked like it expected the probabilities to be over characters, not samples.

Comment: @Lucas: Which function do you minimize exactly? Is it variance (i.e. _(p1-1/total)^2 + (p2-1/total)^2 + .._)? If so, could you comment on why you multiply _1/total_ by _0.5_? I can not figure why that is needed so far. Expanding _(p1-1/total^2)_ results in _p1^2 - 2*p1/total + C_ = _2 * ((1/2)p1^2 - *p1/total + C)_. Since `solvers.qp()` minimizes _(1/2)xPx + qx_, shouldn't there be no need to do `* 0.5` when calculating _q_?

Comment: Its the second order Taylor expansion of the KL divergence (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) between the current distribution and a uniform distribution over all valid strings i.e. `(1/24,1/24,1/24...)` = u, around that distribution ( http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%5Bp+log%28p%2Fq%29%2C+%7Bp%2Cq%2C2%7D%5D - remember q is constant). This, I worked out to be `p^2 - pu`. This formula doesn't have a two in it where the variance does.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the length of a word is always one less than the number of symbols, the following C# code does the job:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;

namespace RandomSymbols
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Sample case:  Four symbols with the following distribution, and 10000 trials
            double[] distribution = { 9.0/30, 8.0/30, 7.0/30, 6.0/30 };
            int trials = 10000;

            // Create an array containing all of the symbols
            char[] symbols = Enumerable.Range('a', distribution.Length).Select(s => (char)s).ToArray();

            // We're assuming that the word length is always one less than the number of symbols
            int wordLength = symbols.Length - 1;

            // Calculate the probability of each symbol being excluded from a given word
            double[] excludeDistribution = Array.ConvertAll(distribution, p => 1 - p * wordLength);

            // Create a random variable using the MathNet.Numerics library
            var randVar = new Categorical(excludeDistribution);
            var random = new Random();
            randVar.RandomSource = random;

            // We'll store all of the words in an array
            string[] words = new string[trials];

            for (int t = 0; t < trials; t++)
            {
                // Start with a word containing all of the symbols
                var word = new List<char>(symbols);

                // Remove one of the symbols
                word.RemoveAt(randVar.Sample());

                // Randomly permute the remainder
                for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
                {
                    int swapIndex = random.Next(wordLength);
                    char temp = word[swapIndex];
                    word[swapIndex] = word[i];
                    word[i] = temp;
                }

                // Store the word
                words[t] = new string(word.ToArray());
            }

            // Display words
            Array.ForEach(words, w => Console.WriteLine(w));

            // Display histogram
            Array.ForEach(symbols, s => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", s, words.Count(w => w.Contains(s))));
        }

    }
}
```

Update: The following is a C implementation of the method that rici outlined.  The tricky part is calculating the thresholds that he mentions, which I did with recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// ****** Change the following for different symbol distributions, word lengths, and number of trials ******
double targetFreqs[] = {10.0/43, 9.0/43, 8.0/43, 7.0/43, 6.0/43, 2.0/43, 1.0/43 };
const int WORDLENGTH = 4;
const int TRIALS = 1000000;
// *********************************************************************************************************

const int SYMBOLCOUNT = sizeof(targetFreqs) / sizeof(double);
double inclusionProbs[SYMBOLCOUNT];

double probLeftToIncludeTable[SYMBOLCOUNT][SYMBOLCOUNT];

// Calculates the probability that there will be n symbols left to be included when we get to the ith symbol.
double probLeftToInclude(int i, int n)
{
    if (probLeftToIncludeTable[i][n] == -1)
    {
        // If this is the first symbol, then the number of symbols left to be included is simply the word length.
        if (i == 0)
        {
            probLeftToIncludeTable[i][n] = (n == WORDLENGTH ? 1.0 : 0.0);
        }
        else
        {
            // Calculate the probability based on the previous symbol's probabilities.
            // To get to a point where there are n symbols left to be included, either there were n+1 symbols left
            // when we were considering that previous symbol and we included it, leaving n,
            // or there were n symbols left and we didn't included it, also leaving n.
            // We have to take into account that the previous symbol may have been manditorily included.
             probLeftToIncludeTable[i][n] = probLeftToInclude(i-1, n+1) * (n == SYMBOLCOUNT-i ? 1.0 : inclusionProbs[i-1])
                + probLeftToInclude(i-1, n) * (n == 0 ? 1.0 : 1 - inclusionProbs[i-1]);
        }
    }
    return probLeftToIncludeTable[i][n];
}

// Calculates the probability that the ith symbol won't *have* to be included or *have* to be excluded.
double probInclusionIsOptional(int i)
{
    // The probability that inclusion is optional is equal to 1.0
    // minus the probability that none of the remaining symbols can be included
    // minus the probability that all of the remaining symbols must be included.
    return 1.0 - probLeftToInclude(i, 0) - probLeftToInclude(i, SYMBOLCOUNT - i);
}

// Calculates the probability with which the ith symbol should be included, assuming that
// it doesn't *have* to be included or *have* to be excluded.
double inclusionProb(int i)
{
    // The following is derived by simple algebra:
    // Unconditional probability = (1.0 * probability that it must be included) + (inclusionProb * probability that inclusion is optional)
    // therefore...
    // inclusionProb = (Unconditional probability - probability that it must be included) / probability that inclusion is optional
    return (targetFreqs[i]*WORDLENGTH - probLeftToInclude(i, SYMBOLCOUNT - i)) / probInclusionIsOptional(i);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Initialize inclusion probabilities
    for (int i=0; i<SYMBOLCOUNT; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<SYMBOLCOUNT; j++)
            probLeftToIncludeTable[i][j] = -1.0;

    // Calculate inclusion probabilities
    for (int i=0; i<SYMBOLCOUNT; i++)
    {
        inclusionProbs[i] = inclusionProb(i);
    }

    // Histogram
    int histogram[SYMBOLCOUNT];
    for (int i=0; i<SYMBOLCOUNT; i++)
    {
        histogram[i] = 0;
    }

    // Scratchpad for building our words
    char word[WORDLENGTH+1];
    word[WORDLENGTH] = '\0';

    // Run trials
    for (int t=0; t<TRIALS; t++)
    {
        int included = 0;

        // Build the word by including or excluding symbols according to the problem constraints
        // and the probabilities in inclusionProbs[].
        for (int i=0; i<SYMBOLCOUNT && included<WORDLENGTH; i++)
        {
            if (SYMBOLCOUNT - i == WORDLENGTH - included // if we have to include this symbol
                || (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX < inclusionProbs[i]) // or if we get a lucky roll of the dice
            {
                word[included++] = 'a' + i;
                histogram[i]++;
            }
        }

        // Randomly permute the word
        for (int i=0; i<WORDLENGTH; i++)
        {
            int swapee = rand() % WORDLENGTH;
            char temp = word[swapee];
            word[swapee] = word[i];
            word[i] = temp;
        }

        // Uncomment the following to show each word
        // printf("%s\r\n", word);
    }

    // Show the histogram
    for (int i=0; i<SYMBOLCOUNT; i++)
    {
        printf("%c: target=%d, actual=%d\r\n", 'a'+i, (int)(targetFreqs[i]*WORDLENGTH*TRIALS), histogram[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to generalize this to work with any word length, not just number of symbols - 1?

Comment: Yes.  See my updated answer where I implemented the approach that rici outlined.

Comment: Fantastic! Works fine. I ran tests which collected the frequencies of all produced triplets and noticed that they are dependent on the order in which symbols are defined in targetFreqs. It seems that the most even result is achieved when they are sorted in the descending frequency order (most probable first), and the most uneven is when they ascend. However, even the most even results which I've managed to get are still slightly worse than the ones produced by the solution of Lucas. Your solution is much more simple, though, which is a really nice property!

Comment: Hmm... you're absolutely right.  It doesn't do well when the target distribution is skewed to the left.  I'll have to think about that.  (P.S. I added memoization so the solution is scalable to alphabets and string lengths in the hundreds.)

Comment: On further testing, it's not just a question of how it's skewed, but it's definitely order-dependent.  I'll work with it some more when I get time since I'm very curious about this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a pretty interesting problem. I don't know the general solution, but it's easy enough to solve in the case of samples of size n-1 (if there is a solution), since there are exactly n possible samples, each of which corresponds to the absence of one of the elements.

Suppose we are seeking F<sub>a</sub> = 9/30, F<sub>b</sub> = 8/30, F<sub>c</sub> = 7/30, F<sub>d</sub> = 6/30 in samples of size 3 from a universe of size 4, as in the OP. We can translate each of those frequencies directly into a frequency of samples by selecting the samples which do not contain the given object. For example, we wish 9/30 of the selected objects to be `a`'s; we cannot have more than one `a` in a sample, and we always have three symbols in a sample; consequently, 9/10 of the samples must contain `a` and 1/10 cannot contain `a`. But there is only one possible sample which doesn't contain `a`: `bcd`. So 10% of the samples must be `bcd`. Similarly, 20% must be `acd`; 30% `abd` and 40% `abc`. (Or, more generally, F<sub>ā</sub> = 1 - (n-1)F<sub>a</sub> where  F<sub>ā</sub> is the frequency of the (unique) sample which does not include `a`)

I can't help thinking that this observation combined with one of the classic ways of generating unique samples can solve the general problem. But I don't have that solution. For what it's worth, the algorithm I'm thinking of is the following:

```
To select a random sample of size k out of a universe U of n objects:
1) Set needed = k; available = n.
2) For each element in U, select a random number in the range [0, 1).
3) If the random number is less than k/n:
     3a) Add the element to the sample.
     3b) Decrement needed by 1. If it reaches 0, we're finished.
4) Decrement available, and continue with the next element in U.
```

So my idea is that it should be possible to manipulate the frequency of element by changing the threshold in step 3, making it somehow a function of the desired frequency of the corresponding element.

Comment: I like your thinking. The problem your method will have is that you may generate one or two characters of a string then not have any choices left. The case where p1=1, for example, will always have this problem. I (of course) think my solution, sloppy articulation aside, is the correct and most general one. Perhaps, only perhaps, your algorithm  is uniformly sampling the probabilities of each string from the set of possible probabilities that conform to the constraints of p1,p2,p3 and p4.

Comment: +1 for your excellent articulation of the solution for k=n-1.  And I think your approach to the general problem could work, with a slight modification -- instead of iterating over U in a certain order, randomly select elements to consider for inclusion in the sample.

Comment: @Kevin, now that I look at your code more carefully, I see that it's implementing the basic k=n-1 solution I outlined, so I guess we're on the same wavelength. Strictly speaking, the standard sampling algorithm doesn't require the elements to be selected in any order, so my description of it was deliberately vague about how you do the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to use a temporary array storing the **cumulated sum** of your probabilities.

In your example, probabilities are 9/30, 8/30, 7/30 and 6/30 respectively.
You should then have an array:

```
values = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
proba = {9/30, 17/30, 24/30, 1}
```

Then you pick a random number `r` in `[0, 1]` and do like this:

```
char chooseRandom() {
    int i = 0;
    while (r > proba[i])
        ++i; 

    return values[i];
}
```

Comment: Your function just chooses a single char. I need a function which would choose 3 of them with no duplicates. And with the correct probabilities.

Comment: Call my function several times and discard duplicates?

Comment: The probabilities would not be correct then, as you would be conditionally discarding symbols.

Comment: They would not be, as the second choice would depend on the first one, and the third choice would depend on both previous ones. Your function will only work if you don't conditionally discard its output. Try it yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: Choose three characters randomly to create a triplet, then discard triplets with repeated symbols

Comment: Well... then you should try finding a solution yourself, right?

Comment: I'm trying to help, but you won't accept my help and won't give arguments as to why my propositions wouldn't work. You didn't even say "thank you for answering". We try to help people like you for free, you should be nicer.

Comment: @alestanis Your solution doesn't work, but I agree with your social commentary somewhat.